# Style binding dependent on later HTML fails

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

So, I'm trying to set the `left` positioning of a `ul` based on the widths of the descendant li elements. The idea is to create a mobile navigation that 'slides' as the active li in the nav bar changes.

I'm trying to render these lis using a KO foreach loop. The only problem is that on initial page load, the selector my style binding is look for is missing. This does work the second time the function is called, when the "active" li changes and the li's it is looking for are present.

I used jQuery here, but I'm sure there's a more "KO way" to do it.

Thanks!

Markup:

```
<nav class="bc-wizard__nav mb2">
    <ul class="bc-wizard__nav-list" data-bind="style: {left: listPosition}">

        <!-- ko foreach: navSections -->
            <li class="bc-wizard__nav-step"
                data-bind="attr: {id: 'nav_section_' + id}, css: $parent.isStepActive(id)">
                <span data-bind="html: title"></span>
            </li>
        <!-- /ko -->

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Knockout function called in binding:

```
self.listPosition = ko.pureComputed(function() {

    // Won't find this on initial load
    var $currentSection = $j('#nav_section_' + self.activeSection());

    var currentPositionInList = $currentSection.position().left;
    var negativeOffset = (currentPositionInList*-1);

    // Moves list horizontally
    return negativeOffset + 'px';
});
```

Comment: can't you delay the computed execution till the html is rendered so you get  valid data i.e `throttle` using computed .

Comment: I didn't know about this feature! It looks useful, but doesn't really help here. The selector still isn't found. 

It seems like this should work, but this in the docs makes me think that the computed _runs_ immediately, it just doesn't tell everything else until  the delay has passed.


"Writes to observables are not delayed ... For writable computed observables, this means that the write function is always run right away." ... "All change notifications are delayed."

Comment: try creating a template for `lis` and use `afterRender` option which should work onLoad but later i'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

I tried several approaches here, including the `afterRender` option on KO templates, and throttle events in a KO computed to try and basically delay the function until the dom rendered.

None of those options worked, but I had a separate function that was adding a class to the active `li`. I just ended up calling the function adjusting the `ul`'s position when this function fires.

A pretty specific solution unfortunately, but there you go.